# iOS: Displaying information from an XML (DTD) file on to the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I am very new to this area but I've been assigned this task.  I have been working on this for three weeks with no success and am hoping someone can either help me or point me in the right direction.

I am trying to display information from a DTD file on to my iOS's screen.  The DTD file is on the web server.  I can Parse the file fine, and everything seems to be working so far.  But when I go to display the information (inside of a tableView) it comes up blank.

What I need to know is this:

- What's the best way TO show the output of the file (tableView, view, etc.?)

I have looked at sample code, read articles, etc. about this topic and am confused about how to SHOW the output.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of possible causes ...it might be useful to post the  table datasource code in your question.  I think the most common cause is a not-hooked-up datasource outlet on the table view.  Please check the table view's connections in the xib/storyboard and make sure it's datasource outlet is connected to the class with the datasource code ([these methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)), probably the view controller that contains the table.

The connection's inspector is the rightmost tab on xcode's righthand pane.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't include the code because I didn't know how at the time I wrote that.  Anyway, your post did help.